# Collecting SQL statements

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird

I would like to ask for advice and some help to make my code more effective. I am working with lots of tables and datas (about 1 million record)
Now I use a Firedac Query with it's simple post. My code works fine but the running takes to long from the start. (more than two hours)
I must updating the parameters field by field. Database is firebird 2.5.

My code looks like...

```
while not qry_sample eof do
begin
  qry_sample.edit;

  for C := 0 to qry_sample.fields.count -1 do
  begin 
   //Here I do the parameter changes for every qry_sample.fields[C].value
   //for example I add new value for all the primary keys and foreign keys 
   //I got the new ID-s from dictionaries
  end;
  qry_sample.post;
end;    
qry_sample.next;
```

But this is very slow...

I would like to make a block with all the table SQL-s and insert together, not one by one

My other code looks like..

```
for C := 0 to qry_SQL.Fields.Count -1 do
begin
  if not vFields.IsEmpty then
    vFields := vFields + ',';

  vFields := vFields + qry_SQL.Fields[C].FieldName;

end;

while not qry_SQL.Eof do
begin
  vValues := '';
  SQL := '';

  for C := 0 to qry_SQL.Fields.Count -1 do
  begin
    vValues := vValues + ',';
    vValues := vValues + chr(39)+ vartostr(qry_SQL.Fields[C].Value) +chr(39);
  end;
  qry_SQL.Next;

  SQL := SQL + #13#10 + 'insert into ' + vSourceTableName + '(' + vFields + ') ' +
  'values ('+ vValues + ');';
end;
```

Variables are variants. After I collected all the SQL-s I want to execute them

Can someone give me a better solution or advice for this? Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Insert the values into a temporary table with no indexes. When you're done do an `insert select` from the temp table into your real table, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115720/insert-select-in-firebird

Comment: Are you using a transaction? i.e. `FDConnection1.StartTransaction` and `FDConnection1.Commit`.

Comment: yeah, Commit after the table posts.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is the wrong way round:

```
while not qry_sample eof do
begin
  qry_sample.edit;

  for C := 0 to qry_sample.fields.count -1 do
  begin 
  end;
  qry_sample.post;
end;    
qry_sample.next;
```

You loop over every line of the query and inside that you loop over every field.
But the field metadata inside a query stays the same every line.
Pull the two loops apart like so:

```
type
  TFieldData = record
    //Whatever data you want to collect about the fields
  end;

var
  Fields: array of TFieldData;
begin
  SetLength(Fields, qry_sample.Field.Count);
  for c:= 0 to qry_sample.Fields.Count -1 do begin
    //Store the relevant data in the fields array
    Fields[c].Fieldname:= qry_sample.Fields[i].Fieldname;
  end; {for fields}
  while not(qry_sample.eof) do begin
    //Do stuff
  end; {while}
  qry_sample.post;
```

By pulling the collection for row metadata and the posting of updates out of the loop you should speed up things quite a lot.

**Still not fast enough**

- Collect the row data in a custom array (see above).
- Use this data to create a temporary table with no indexes.
- Insert data into the temporary
  table.
- Disable indexing on the real table(s).
- Do a select-insert (select-update) from the temp table to the real table(s).
- Enable indexing on the real table(s).
- Drop the temp table.